# Live testing so annoying and time-consuming

Tags: etherscan, testnets, brownie, unittesting, test

After days of unit local testing i begin testing on testnet, and it turns that i have some errors that appear from nowhere, to fix those errors i need to redeploy all the contracts and arrange all the conditions (imagine how many times) to test that whether using scripts or etherscan, what i was doing instantly localy. Is there any trick or solution are you guys working with to make life much easier ?

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely why we have local testing which makes debugging and working quite faster. The testnets are also getting colossal daily and hence, slower too.

Regarding errors, brownie is a very good framework to work with and provides the same outputs as the testnet or mainnet would. So, errors should not be prevalent
case other than transaction failure.